# Pattern Matching to find the web address present in a web page

Tags: java, pattern-matching

Can any one suggest me how to match string patterns, where One string is

`(\\.quantserve\\.com\\/|\\/quant\\.js)`$

and which needed to be matched to

`edge.quantserve.com/quant.js`$.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `java.util.regex.Pattern` Object to match String-objects in Java.
Your example would be something like:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*\\.quantserve\\.com/.*quant\\.js");
boolean b = p.matcher("edge.quantserve.com/quant.js").matches();
System.out.println(b);
```

Edit: Debug in Pattern

Comment: Sorry, little typo in the pattern, I missed the .* in the beginning of the pattern.